# I want to fetch specific array element record from array in mongodb document using MongoDB java api

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I had one document with multiple array elements.
I want to find some specific values from array.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a67aa569f2bc6a5865f220"),       
    "language" : "us_english",
    "country" : "united states",
    "state" : "texas",
    "words" : [ 
        {

            "handle" : "gm",
            "replacement" : "good morning",

        }, 
        {

            "handle" : "ilu",
            "replacement" : "i love you",

        }
    ]
}
```

I want find value of `replacement` where `handle is gm` and `language is english` , `country is united states` and `state is texas`.

I tried many solutions but i cant able to find specific value from document.

Is there any solution ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation operation.

- [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#match-aggregation) to filter the documents
- [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-aggregation) to deconstruct the `words` field
- Reuse `$match` to find value of `replacement` field

  ```
  db.collection.aggregate([{$match : {language : 'us_english', country: 'united states', state: 'texas'}}, {$unwind: '$words'}, {$match: {"words.handle" : "gm"}}])

  { "_id" : ObjectId("54a67aa569f2bc6a5865f220"), "language" : "us_english", "country" : "united states", "state" : "texas", "words" : { "handle" : "gm", "replacement" : "good morning" } }
  ```

Comment: Hello @Styvane, Thanks for your reply. But i want this solution using MongoDB java API.